# A CMS for a beginner developer

Tags: html, css, cms, design

I am a beginner developer who knows HTML, CSS  and lately have entered in web development world with learning some beginning php scripts.
I just want to know is there a clean CMS that allows me to lunch a dynamic website including forms and registration with my current knowlege? (i don't want a CMS limit my created HTML page in design.)

And for last, it is very useful if this CMS be rich in functional developments, maybe in future i can develop bigger projects, and just for mention i don't like using too many plugins for sample things, i just want this CMS be functionaly easy and do not limit me.

thanks

Comment: I have added more information about my question, please don't mark as duplicate. my question is more specific than you refered.

Comment: We don't accept specific questions about CMS systems outside of one catch-all question.